# nodemcu EEPROM corrupting

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, nodemcu, eeprom

Platform

- Hardware:                 [nodemcu amica ESP8266MOD]
- Core Version:         [nodemcu-master-21-modules-2018-03-17-17-09-10]
- Development Env:      [Arduino IDE|]
- Operating System:     [Windows|]

#### Settings in IDE

- Module:           |Nodemcu]
- Flash Mode:           [qio|dio|other]?
- Flash Size:       [1MB]
- lwip Variant:   [v2 Lower Memory]
- Reset Method:     [nodemcu]
- Flash Frequency:  [40Mhz]
- CPU Frequency:        [80Mhz]
- Upload Using:     [SERIAL]
- Upload Speed:   [115200] (serial upload only)

#### Problem Description

hi, in my code i did a simple thing. i get the data from jSon object and write them to the EEPROM. once i write them to eeprom i can read the relevant data from that writing function `handleFinishWizard()`  (i have put reading functions here n there to find where is the problem) .When i write data and finish it i can read the data.once its over when the program moved to the loop, eeprom data are corrupted and it doesnt display anything. i attached the output in debug message. whats the problem here?

#### [MCVE] Sketch

code in github [CODE LINK](https://github.com/namila007/mediot-hardware/blob/dev_print/main/main.ino)

#### Debug Messages

````
```
add 1
aid 1
station: c0:ee:fb:ed:3b:0e join, AID = 1
value on EEPROM ADD: 
OnePlus 3T
test123@abc
test.com

value on EEPROM ADD: 
OnePlus 3T
test123@abc
test.com

value on EEPROM ADD: 
OnePlus 3T
test123@abc
test.com

value on EEPROM ADD: 
OnePlus 3T
test123@abc
test.com

value on EEPROM ADD: 
OnePlus 3T
test123@abc
test.com

value on EEPROM saveBefore: 
⸮?

⸮?

value on EEPROM saveBefore: 
⸮?

⸮?

value on EEPROM saveBefore: 
⸮?

⸮?

value on EEPROM saveBefore: 
⸮?

⸮?

value on EEPROM saveBefore: 
⸮?

⸮?

value on EEPROM save: 




value on EEPROM save: 




value on EEPROM save:
````

```

Comment: use SPIFFS with 8266, so much better than EEPROM

Comment: @dandavis yes after the problem i moved to SPIFFS. saved data in json format.easy

Comment: EEPROM has 100K cycles of recording data and then it will probably stop.  Have you written to this EEPROM more than 100K times?

Comment: @tonygil no, this happened because of I wrote pointers instead of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
void setupCredentials(const char *ssid, const char *password,
                      const char *link) {
  int addr = 0;

  EEPROM.begin(512);
  addr = sizeof(int);
  EEPROM.put(addr, ssid);
  delay(10);
  addr += sizeof(st_ssid);
  EEPROM.put(addr, password);
  delay(10);
  addr += sizeof(st_password);
  EEPROM.put(addr, link);
  delay(10);
  EEPROM.commit();
```

You are calling `EEPROM.put(addr, ssid)` with `ssid` being a `const char*`. A pointer to some memory location. Notice that you only give it a start address and a pointer, not the length of your data.

Have a look at the implementation of the [`put` function](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/EEPROM/EEPROM.h):

```
  template<typename T> 
  const T &put(int const address, const T &t) {
    if (address < 0 || address + sizeof(T) > _size)
      return t;
    if (memcmp(_data + address, (const uint8_t*)&t, sizeof(T)) != 0) {
      _dirty = true;
      memcpy(_data + address, (const uint8_t*)&t, sizeof(T));
    }

    return t;
}
```

What it essentially does is copy your given object `const T &t` into its internal `_data`buffer. The size of the data saved is determined by `sizeof(T)`.

In your example `t = ssid`, `T = const char*` and `sizeof(T) = sizeof(char*) = 4` and `addr= sizeof(int) = 4`.

What you are doing here is not to save the string that `ssid` points to in memory but the **pointer value** of `ssid`. After you leave the function the data pointed to by `ssid` will be de-allocated at some point and the memory will be overwritten by something else.

When you do a print directly in the function you are retrieving the pointer value of `ssid` 3 times and print that value. At that point the data is still there and everything is okay. Then if you print it again after leaving the function you get garbage because the local data is gone after the function call `handleSetup` is left.

What you want here is to not use a `const char*` in your second argument to a  `EEPROM.put(address, object)` call but a `char [20]`, for example. This way the `put` will work correctly.

Example:

```
// Assume EEPROM.begin() was called already
void EEPROM_SaveSSID(const int address, const char* str) {
    char ssid_buf[20];
    strncpy(ssid_buf, sizeof(ssid_buf) - 1, str);
    EEPROM.put<char[20]>(address, ssid_buf[0]); //sizeof(ssid_buf) = 20
    //don't forget to EEPROM.commit(); and EEPROM.end()
}

/* read SSID into a pre-allocated buffer */
void EEPROM_ReadSSID(const int address, char ssid_buf[20]) {
    EEPROM.get(address, ssid_buf); //sizeof(ssid_buf) = 20
}
```

If you do not like the semantics of these C++-templates auto-determining the size of read/write calls, you can always use bytewise `read` and `write` calls:

```
void EEPROM_SaveSSID(const int address, const char* str) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str)) {
        EEPROM.write((int)(address + i), str[i]);
    }
}

/* always read 20 bytes starting from given address into buffer */
void EEPROM_ReadSSID(const int address, char ssid_buf[20]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ssid_buf); i++) {
        ssid_buf[i] = EEPROM.read((int)(address + i));
    }
}
```

See "EEPROM" (actually: Flash-emulated EEPROM) implementation code at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/EEPROM.